# Convert loop logic to LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

Does anyone know if there's a cleaner way of doing this (maybe LINQ)? I want to group the value into bucket, and give it a score, so for example in the code below, if the value is:

- less or equal to 5, increase the score by 1
- 10 and below, increase score by 2
- 15 and below, increase score by 3
- else increase by 4.

There are about 10 properties that I have to do this for, and each property have different range for scoring.

```
public static PScore GetScore(IEnumerable<PStat> rs)
    {
        var data = new PScore();

        foreach(var item in rs)
        {
            if(item.Kill <= 5)
            {
                data.Kills++;
            }
            else if (item.Kill <= 10)
            {
                data.Kills += 2;
            }
            else if (item.Kill <= 15)
            {
                data.Kills += 3;
            }
            else
            {
                data.Kills += 4;
            }
        }

        return data;
    }
```

edit#1
Thanks everyone, the ranges varied as well, and I have 10 properties to loop through, so I use this and just passed in the value and ranges

```
public static int GetScoreASC(int value, int[] range)
    {

        if (value <= range[0])
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else if (value <= range[1])
        {
            return 2;
        }
        else if (value <= range[2])
        {
            return 3;
        }
        else if (value <= range[3])
        {
            return 4;
        }
        else if (value <= range[4])
        {
            return 5;
        }
        else if (value <= range[5])
        {
            return 6;
        }
        else if (value <= range[6])
        {
            return 7;
        }
        else if (value <= range[7])
        {
            return 8;
        }
        else if (value <= range[8])
        {
            return 9;
        }
        else
        {
            return 10;
        }
    }
```

This way I can reused the same method for all properties.

Comment: I think the answer is no. Remove the redundant braces to gain screen space and I think this code is fine.

Answer (score 3):

I would do some math per each property using LINQ:

```
public static PScore GetScore(IEnumerable<PStat> rs)
{
   var data = new PScore();
   data.Kills = rs.Sum(item => Math.Min(item.Kill / 5 + (item.Kill % 5 == 0 ? 0 : 1), 4));
   return data;
}
```

Comment: That's a very specialized math trick that is a) incomprehensible and b) too specific for his needs. He has a different scheme for different purposes. In fact from this answer I realize that the question is purely opinion based and I just voted to close.

Comment: It's also incorrect. When `item.Kill` is `5`, it adds `5 / 5 + 1` which is `2`. It should add `1`.

Comment: I've corrected my formula but this is less important here - it is not very specialized math trick, just math. And allows to easily change grouping value (5) and maxmimum score (4) into any other values without rewriting many lines of `if`s. Hence it can be reused (with those two parameters provided) for other properties.

Answer (score 3):

You can repeat yourself less by using `Select` to grab the `Kill` values from `rs` and then `Sum` to aggregate across them.

```
public static PScore GetScore(IEnumerable<PStat> rs)
{
    return new PScore
    {
        Kills = rs.Select(item => item.Kill).Sum(kill =>
        {
            if (kill <= 5) return 1;
            if (kill <= 10) return 2;
            if (kill <= 15) return 3;
            return 4;
        })
    };
}
```

If you like Konrad's style of converting the conditionals to a closed form computation, you need to correct his formula slightly. I personally would stick with the conditionals for this, though.

```
public static PScore GetScore(IEnumerable<PStat> rs)
{
    return new PScore
    {
        Kills = rs.Select(item => item.Kill)
            .Sum(kill => Math.Max(1, Math.Min((kill + 4) / 5, 4)));
    };
}
```

Comment: Good. You han leave out all the `else` keywords.

Comment: Inside the object initializer you ude a semicolon `;` arter the property assignment. I think that must be a comma `,`. One could consider using a named method instead of the lambda, as in `.Sum(GetKillScore)`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Browser code. :) Thanks for the catch.